# Rails AssociationTypeMismatch on object sent by a check_box_tag inside a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails is getting me this error Subject(#70287575068140) expected, got String(#70287576459120), but my parameters are:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rISZVyQZgcLCGP1y7F4qg7xmW1miuaJvwUe5gu59/MqjjSWem/3JzCei5EPuZSSVdZyqO8bq0eRk0w9zCo0mDA==",
 "student"=>{"name"=>"Eduardo Pedroso",
 "rg"=>"39468291-0",
 "phone"=>"981713271",
 "address"=>"Rua dr Camilo marques",
 "birthday"=>"2015-06-08",
 "scholarity"=>"Superior",
 "responsible_id"=>"1",
 "subjects"=>["#<Subject:0x007fda346828e0>",
  "#<Subject:0x007fda34682660>"]},
 "commit"=>"Edit student",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

And the checkbox that sends the subjects params

```
    <% Subject.all.each do |subject| %>
      <%= check_box_tag :subjects_id, subject, @student.subjects.include?(subject), :name => 'student[subjects][]' -%>
      <%= label_tag :subjects, subject.name %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<%= check_box_tag :subjects_id, subject, @student.subjects.include?(subject), :name => 'student[subjects][]' -%>
```

to

```
<%= check_box_tag :subjects_id, subject, @student.subjects.include?(subject), :name => 'student[subjects_id][]' -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You better check the definitions around the [check_box_tag helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)

It goes like this:

> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})

So comparing with your use, you have assigned the `name` attribute twice and assigned as value the object `subject`.

I believe you intended to assign the `subject.id` as value, so you can fix it by replacing the `check_box_tag` call as:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'student[subjects][]', subject.id, @student.subjects.include?(subject) -%>
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I still got the same error message.